# Perl - Argument unable to detect in Directory name

Tags: perl

I was trying to get directory from Argument0 but the argument name was not show in directory when i print it out. Below is the script i am writing. I am using unix to run the perl program. Running Try.pl script file with command  ./Try.pl Device1 .

The Output should be : /home/Folder/Master_File/Device1
As my argument0 was Device1. 
But for now my output was /home/Folder/Master_File/$device

Can you help to advices what is going on with it. Thanks.

```
my $device;
$device = "$ARGV[0]";

print "$device\n";    # Device1

my $directory = '/home/Folder/Master_File/$device';

print "$directory\n"; # /home/Folder/Master_File/$device

print "$ARGV[0]\n";   # Device1

print "$device\n";    # Device1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
'/home/Folder/Master_File/$device'
```

should be

```
"/home/Folder/Master_File/$device"
```

or

```
'/home/Folder/Master_File/' . $device
```

Single-quote don't interpolate.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination .